# How to make the button image fill it?

Tags: html, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to apply an image to a xtype='button' however when i do it my button looks like this

[image]

How can i make this image fill this button ?

Code (sencha touch 2 js):

```
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            width: 140,
            height: 60,
            margin: 10,
            right: 20,  

            text: 'Enter',
            html: '<img src="resources/images/Dbutton.png"/>'
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the image is a background image on the button, then use the CSS property `background-size`.

```
.mybutton {
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Note that this won't work in IE8 or earlier. You'd need to use a polyfill javascript if you want IE8 support. Try this one: https://github.com/louisremi/jquery.backgroundSize.js

Hope that helps.

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped. If you need it to work in IE8, make sure you implement a work-around for it and test it in that browser as well.

Answer (score 3):

to work on all browsers, change the html to

```
    <input type='image' src='filename.png' width='25' height='25' name='whatever' value='submit' />
```

this uses the image as a submit button.